# Typescript: Remove all vowel except when it is the leading character

Tags: javascript, typescript, string, filter

I would like to remove all the vowels from the string excluding the first character in TypeScript.

For example 'abced' to 'abcd'.

Comment: Have you figured out how to do it in *JavaScript* first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is a way to do it with just regex but you can just strip the first char when replacing and add it back after.

```
const myString = "abced";

myString.substring(0,1) + myString.substring(1).replaceAll(/[aeiou]/ig,"");
```

note that the regex `/[aeiou]/ig` is case insensitive because of the `i` after the second `/`

Answer (score 1):

You could use reqexp with positive look behind

```js
console.log('abcedufoi'.replace(/(?<=.)([aeiou])/gi, ''))
```

Comment: Do not do this; it is awful for performance; every vowel needs to be tested for the character in front. Lookbehind is notoriously slow. You can do something like `/.+([aeiouy])/ig`

Comment: @Akxe Nope, your expression wont work `console.log('abcedufoi'.replace(/.+([aeiouy])/ig, ''))` You don't want to capture the symbol.